# Passing a JSON object to a ASPX page from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm have a page that's rendered in JS that loads some info from the server that the user can edit. The page has a "pop out" option (similar to gmail when you compose an email and can pop it out to another window).

Here's my problem, if the user changes any of the info in the page I don't want that to be lost when the page is popped out. There is far too much information in the page to pass it all in the URL so I was thinking the best way would be to send a JSON object to the ASPX page and have it parse the information into itself.

I've seen this done through Web Services but I was wondering if it would be possible to do it just through an ASPX page. Am I even on the right track or is there a better way to get the data from the JS code into the ASPX page that I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a PageMethod on the ASPX page, and use that to process the JSON data.

Take a look at this nice article from Encosia.com: http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Well i think that's kind of what you are trying to do here, right? Make a behind-the-scenes call to the server to save some data? Defining a PageMethod is quite easy, and the jquery syntax for the AJAX call is also pretty straightforward. Are you not able to use AJAX for some reason?

Comment: I was hoping to open a new aspx window entirely whose data is parsed out from a JSON object. So I was thinking that a static method wouldn't work for a single instance of the aspx page unless it stored that data into the server which the instance page then retrieved. That seems more complicated than just sending the data to the page. Am I missing something?

Comment: probably you are looking for Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx , you can always post the current page to the new (target) page. it is actually easier than Ajax.

Comment: Turns out what I could get a reference to the popup window and assign a value to that window which the popup could then reference. It's all client side and super fast. Any thoughts on this solution?

Answer (score 2):

the answer is yes. you can use call page method from client side

[here is an example using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)